# Sometimes MongoDB does not update when running multiple update statement using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a script which contains multiple functions with an update statement. As shown below. Each function is performing a different task which is to update my Product2 collection with specific details. All of this is happening in one python script. My problem is when I run my script then there are at times it does not update properly. It's only when I run the script again then I can see everything has been updated. Is this the right way to do my update or am I missing something ?. Please help. I am using MongoDB 4.2.0

```
def stat1()
    db.Products2.update({updatesomething},upsert=False)

def stat2()
    db.Products2.update({updatesomething},upsert=False)

def stat3()
    db.Products2.update({updatesomething},upsert=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stat1()
    stat2()
    stat3()
```

Answer (score 0):

`update()` has been deprecated for quite a while now. In any case, your usage is incorrect; the update operators `replace_one()` / `update_one()` / `update_many()` need to know what to update, and this is done using a `filter` parameter; something like:

```
db.Products2.update_one(filter={filter}, update={updatesomething}, upsert=False)
```